# DB2 Dependency table

Tags: sql, database, db2

Can you please mention DB2 Dependency catalog table, to find the dependency present between table and view, table and indexes and table and triggers with example.

In Oracle I can use All_Dependencies table and query it for table and view

```
SELECT * From All_Dependencies
WHERE Type = 'VIEW' AND
      Referenced_Owner = 'ownerName' AND
      Referenced_Type = 'TABLE' AND
      Referenced_Name = 'tableName'
```

In DB2 there is `SYSIBM.SYSDEPENDENCIES` table but I am finding it difficult to query.

Comment: Hey does the above question makes sense!!!. Or do you want some more clarity on it!!

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? What makes it seem more difficult?

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the [Info Center entry](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsysdependenciestable.htm) for `SYSIBM.SYSDEPENDENCIES`?

It has all the columns, and how they work.

Comment: ya I checked that and I executed in database but its not giving me all the attributes that I get when I execute All_Dependencies in Oracle.

I think there is some other catalog table which retrieves all the attributes

Comment: Are there some particular attributes you are looking for that aren't in that catalog view (I'm not an Oracle person, so I don't know what is available in that `All_Dependencies` table)?

Comment: Hey bhamby thanks for your response. It would be better if you can mention simple query using SYSIBM.SYSDEPENDENCIES

Comment: In all_dependencies you will get view name and the table name that are dependent on each other for the query I mentioned in question

Comment: I got the table name dependent index name and trigger name using syscat.indexes and syscat.triggers repectively, but not getting table name dependent on views using syscat.triggers. So I started looking in sysibm.dependencies table

Answer (score 1):

We will infer that you are talking about DB2 for z/OS, since you discuss SYSIBM.SYSDEPENDENCIES which does not exist under that name in [DB2 LUW](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0011297.html) 
or [DB2 for i](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzcatalog.htm).  Other members of the DB2 family have different catalog views, with different information.

Look in the [DB2 10 for z/OS Info Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc%2Fsrc%2Falltoc%2Fdb2z_10_prodhome.htm) under [catalog tables](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_catalogtablesintro.htm).  There you will find more detailed for specific object types, such as [SYSIBM.SYSVIEWDEP](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_sysibmsysviewdeptable.htm) with information about view dependencies.